# TSQL GROUP BY in recursive CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

Is there a workaround to use GROUP BY inside a looping CTE or there is a workaround?

I need to group resultset of a CTE table and use it in another loop with the same CTE, but i get following error:

> GROUP BY, HAVING, or aggregate functions are not allowed in the
>   recursive part of a recursive common table expression 'cte'.

Here's the query:

```
WITH cte
    AS
    (
        SELECT
          id,
          dailyconsumption,
          stock/dailyconsumption as cutoff
        FROM items
        WHERE father IS NULL


        UNION ALL

        SELECT
          i.id,
          SUM(father.dailyconsumption*i.num),
          MAX(stock)/SUM(father.dailyconsumption*i.num)
        FROM cte father
        JOIN items i ON father.id=i.father
        group by i.id
    )

SELECT id, MIN(cutoff)
FROM cte
GROUP BY id
```

[**SQL-Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4f2a/11) (with sample data)

---

**EDIT... this is the logical problem**

I have a set of end-user items (father=NULL) and other sub-items made by a number of other items (field father and field num populated).
I got the dailyconsumption just for the end-user items (I start my cte with "WHERE father IS NULL"), and sub-items's dailyconsumption are calculate by SUM(father.dailyconsumption *item.num).

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT
      id,
      dailyconsumption,
      stock/dailyconsumption as cutoff
    FROM items
    WHERE father IS NULL


    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      i.id,
      father.dailyconsumption*i.num
      0
    FROM cte father
    JOIN items i ON father.id=i.father
)

SELECT id, SUM(dailyconsumption)
FROM cte
GROUP BY id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4f2a/95

With this **valid** query I'm going to have all dailyconsumption populated for all items (end-user and sub-items). Please mind that father-son relationship can be more than 1 level deep.

Now i need to calculate the cutoff (for how many days my stock is enought).
For end-use it is very easy and already calculated in first CTE: **stock/dailyconsumption**.
For sub-items it is a little more complicated: 
**subitem.stock/subitem.dailyconsumption + MIN(father.cutoff)**
where MIN(father.cutoff) is the minimun cutoff from all fathers of this subitem.
This is because i need another group by.

May I need another CTE to loop in the same father-son relationship?

Thank you for your attention and sorry for my English.

Comment: What is the meaning of grouping in the recursive part of cte? I assume you have tree, then item.id will be unique on each iteration.

Comment: What would be the desired result (using the data in your SQL-Fiddle)?

Comment: Apparently, you can't have any GROUP BY nor AGGREGATE function when using recursive table...

Comment: Could you please give expected result set for the fiddle data?  May have good solution.

Answer (score 5):

```
;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT id, father, 
         dailyconsumption,
         (stock / dailyconsumption) AS cutoff,
         0 AS [Level] 
  FROM items
  WHERE father IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT i.id, i.father, 
         c.dailyconsumption * i.num,
         i.stock / (c.dailyconsumption * i.num),
         [Level] + 1
  FROM cte c JOIN items i ON c.id = i.father
  )
  SELECT c.id, c.dailyconsumption, c.cutoff AS subItemsCutoff, 
         MIN(ct.cutoff) OVER(PARTITION BY ct.[Level]) AS fatherCutoff,
         (c.cutoff  + ISNULL(MIN(ct.cutoff) OVER(PARTITION BY ct.[Level]), 0)) AS Cutoff
  FROM cte c LEFT JOIN cte ct ON c.father = ct.id
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/84ed4/3/0)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a variable table instead. Declare the table and then insert those records into it. You would need to figure out a way to loop through it on the second insert into command. I got this to get you started:

```
DECLARE @staging TABLE
(
    id                  INT
    ,dailyconsumption   FLOAT
    ,cutoff             FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO @staging
    SELECT
      id,
      dailyconsumption,
      stock/dailyconsumption as cutoff
    FROM 
      items
    WHERE 
      father IS NULL

INSERT INTO @staging
  SELECT
      i.id,
      SUM(father.dailyconsumption*i.num),
      MAX(stock)/SUM(father.dailyconsumption*i.num)
    FROM 
      @staging father

        JOIN items i 
        ON father.id=i.father
    group by 
      i.id

SELECT 
  id
 ,MIN(cutoff)
FROM 
  @staging
GROUP BY 
  id
```

Comment: Why is that? He can select from it after inserting into it.

Comment: That does one level of recursion, but the CTE will keep recursing deeper than that until the very bottom of the tree.  I guess you could do it with a table variable, but you'd have to also use some type of `while` loop to recurse all the way down the tree.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I think that creating a loop on the second insert into command should work.