# Recursivly Join Closest Ancestor/Parent To Record In Same Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

As-per the title of this question I am trying to have a record join with another record recursively in the same table with a specific property (whichever parent record closest) but am not entirely sure how to go about this one.

I checked [here](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956368/tsql-group-by-in-recursive-cte?rq=1) but sadly were not specific enough for my required use-case.

Example SQLFiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0c5fb/2

The end result I am trying to achieve is something like this where each row knows its closest ancestor where NeededElement is true:

| ElementID | ElementName | NeededElement | ParentElementID | ClosestNeededElementID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Root Element | true | (null) | (null) |
| 2 | Child Element A | true | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | Child Element B | false | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | Child Element AA | false | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | Child Element AB | false | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | Child Element BA | false | 3 | 1 |
| 7 | Child Element BB | false | 3 | 1 |

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following modification to your shared query.

```sql
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT
  ElementID,
  ElementName,
  NeededElement,
  ParentElementID,
  ParentElementID as NextParentElementID, 
  CAST(NULL AS INT) as ClosestNeededElementID
  FROM TestElements
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT
      CTE.ElementID,
      CTE.ElementName,
      CTE.NeededElement,
      CTE.ParentElementID,
      TestElements.ParentElementID as NextParentElementID,
      CASE 
          WHEN TestElements.NeededElement=1 THEN TestElements.ElementID
      END AS ClosestNeededElementID
  FROM CTE
  INNER JOIN TestElements ON CTE.NextParentElementID = TestElements.ElementID 
  WHERE CTE.ClosestNeededElementID IS NULL 
)
SELECT 
   ElementID,
  ElementName,
  NeededElement,
  ParentElementID,
  ClosestNeededElementID
FROM CTE
WHERE (ParentElementId IS NULL) OR (ClosestNeededElementId IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY ElementID ASC
```

[View working demo fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/51953c/6/0)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Fantastic that's it thanks! :)

Looks like I'm going to need to brush up on my SQL common table expressions!

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a running column for the closest parent by using a conditional:

```
with cte(id, name, n_elem, p, l) as (
   select *, null from testelements where parentelementid is null
   union all
   select t.*, case when c.n_elem = 1 then c.id else c.l end
   from cte c join testelements t on t.parentelementid = c.id
)
select * from cte;
```